# Objective-Cで右から左にモーダルで画面遷移する方法は？

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone

Objective-Cでモーダルでの画面遷移を行っています。 
プッシュではなくモーダルで、プッシュでの画面遷移のように 
右から左、左から右へ画面が移動できる方法はありますか？

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/28466 マルチポスト

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のSegueを定義しておいて

```
@interface MySegue : UIStoryboardSegue
@end

@implementation MySegue
- (void)perform {
    __block CGRect dFrame = self.destinationViewController.view.frame;
    dFrame.origin.x = dFrame.size.width;
    self.destinationViewController.view.frame = dFrame;
    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [window insertSubview:self.destinationViewController.view aboveSubview:self.sourceViewController.view];
// Viewを載せるのは以下でも良い
//    [self.sourceViewController.view addSubview:self.destinationViewController.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        dFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
        self.destinationViewController.view.frame = dFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.sourceViewController presentViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }];
}
@end
```

以下を実行すると右から左に遷移します。

```
- (IBAction)showSecondView:(id)sender {
    [[[MySegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" source:self destination:[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]] perform];
}
```

戻る時はUnwind Segueに戻る為のアニメーションのSegueを作って使えば良いです。

Segueを利用しなくてもSegueのperformで行っている処理を書けば利用する事はできますが、再利用性を考えるとSegueを定義しておくと良いと思います。

**追記**

dismissする時は以下のようなSegueを作成して、StoryboardでしたらExitに接続してUnwindSegueにこのクラスを設定すると逆向き風のアニメーションになります。（このアニメーションはSource/Destinationどちらも動くようになっています。）

```
@interface MyUnwindSegue : UIStoryboardSegue
@end

@implementation MyUnwindSegue
- (void)perform {
    __block CGRect sFrame = self.sourceViewController.view.frame;

    __block CGRect dFrame = self.destinationViewController.view.frame;
    dFrame.origin.x = -dFrame.size.width;
    self.destinationViewController.view.frame = dFrame;
    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [window insertSubview:self.destinationViewController.view aboveSubview:self.sourceViewController.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        sFrame.origin.x = sFrame.size.width;
        self.sourceViewController.view.frame = sFrame;

        dFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
        self.destinationViewController.view.frame = dFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.sourceViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }];
}
@end
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました！
ちなみに元の画面に戻る時ですが、
[self.view.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
のようにモーダルで遷移したVCを削除しつつ、先ほどのような左右からスライドすることは可能でしょうか？

Comment: dismiss用のsegueを追記しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
移動はできたのですが、MySegueを使って画面A→画面B→画面Cに移動すると、画面BとCの間で値の受け渡しができず、MyUnwindSegueを使って画面CからBに戻るとタッチが検出されず、画面Aに戻ることができませんでした。
また、数回MySegueとMyUnwindSegueを使って遷移をし続けると、途中から画面遷移できなくなってしまいました....

Comment: MyUnwindSegueはStoryboardでExitに接続して作成したUnwind Segueに設定されていますか？